# Java-2D: How to draw arc?

Tags: java, java-2d

I am drawing some figures with the java graphics 2d library, i stuck while drawing an arc. My objective is to draw the following two arcs:
)
( 
I am using the following code:

```
g2.draw(new Arc2D.Double(x, y,
                         rectwidth,
                         rectheight,
                         90, 135,
                         Arc2D.OPEN));
```

but this code draws some strange type of arc, i am sure with the x,y,width and height params. But i am doubtful about the next two params i am sure that i am doing some thing wrong but i dont know whats that :(

Comment: do you need explanation of parameters of constructor ?       ellipseBounds - The bounding rectangle that defines the outer boundary of the full ellipse of which this arc is a partial section.
start - The starting angle of the arc in degrees. (Specified in double precision.)
extent - The angular extent of the arc in degrees. (Specified in double precision.)
type - The closure type for the arc: OPEN, CHORD, or PIE.

Comment: Can you give an image what you want and what you got?