# How to draw semi circle

Tags: java, java-2d

I am developing a small application in Java. I am using Java2D Library for drawing some graphical objects. Now i want to draw some semi-circle like shape or in simple words i need to draw this `(` shape and this `)` shape. I didn't find any function for drawing semi-circle, but i guess that `Arc2D.Double(. . .);`
will work for me, so i tried it but i didn't understand what params i need to pass to its constructor. So i end up with the strange kind of shape :(

Could some one explains these params in detail or refer to some good link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java-2D: How to draw arc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060697/java-2d-how-to-draw-arc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To draw `(`

```
Arc2D.Double(x, y, w, h, 90, 180, Arc2D.OPEN)
```

And for `)`

```
Arc2D.Double(x, y, w, h, 90, -180, Arc2D.OPEN)
```

The parameters are explained here: [Arc2D.Double](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Arc2D.Double.html)

The method I have used here is: [Arc2D.Double(double, double, double, double, double, double, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Arc2D.Double.html#Arc2D.Double%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20int%29)

This [link](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/java2d/java2dpart1.html) can also help.

Answer (score 1):

You need use 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Arc2D.Double.html.

```
Arc2D.Double(double x, double y, double w, double h, double start, double extent, int type)
```

`x,y` - location (x,y), 
`w, h` - size , 
`start, extent` - angular extents (you need  |extent - start| = 180)